# How to convert radio buttons to select in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to convert radio buttons to select boxes in jquery.

I have the following code, but it doesn't produce what I need:

```
$j('#product_addtocart_form input[type=radio]').each(function(i, checkbox){
var $checkbox = $j(checkbox);
// create a select
var $select = $j('<select></select>');
// set name and value
$select.attr('name', $checkbox.attr('name')).attr('value', $checkbox.val());
$select.append(new Option('test','tet'));
//$checkbox.remove();
});
```

Comment: "Please do my work" questions will be closed, always.

Answer (score 9):

You're recreating the `$select` inside the loop each time. Also, your `$select` is never written out to the browser.

Try this:

```
var $checkbox = $('#product_addtocart_form input[type=radio]');
var $select = $('<select></select>');    // create a select
$select.attr('name', $checkbox.attr('name'));    // set name and value

$checkbox.each(function(i, checkbox){
    var str = $checkbox.eq(i).val();
    $select.append($('<option>').val(str).text(str));
});

$checkbox.replaceWith($select);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/G9fHG/

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to [accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/171394) to encourage others to help you again in the future.

Comment: With a little customisation, it works like a charm. Thanks!